# Cannot see files under "Camera" in Android, developed in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, permissions

I am trying to list (to display) pictures using a flutter coded APP on my Android device.
This is the code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();
//String path = '/home/saulocho/Downloads/Photos-001';
String path = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera';
Directory dir = Directory(path);
//var images = dir.listSync().where((image) => image.path.endsWith(".jpg"));
var images = dir.listSync();
debugPrint('Directory counter: ${images.length} in path $path');
debugPrint(images[images.length-1].path);

final cards = images.map((image)=>ImageCard(photo: Image.file(File(image.path),fit: BoxFit.cover,),)).toList();
debugPrint('Image cards counter: ${cards.length} in path $path');
debugPrint(images[0].path);
```

I do have files there indeed, I have tried also without the filter on "jpg". But this is the output of the Debug:

> I/flutter (25676): Directory counter: 2 in path /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera
> I/flutter (25676): /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/HMD
> I/flutter (25676): Image cards counter: 2 in path /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera
> I/flutter (25676): /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/raw

Despite I can see this if I connect via mount to the phone:

[image: DCIM folder]

I would say I have enabled the right permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
```

but when launching in debug mode from Android developer, I receive no alert asking for them.

What am I missing?

I'd thank any help :)

Answer (score 1):

In flutter with android, the permissions are not delivered automatically. Even if you declare them in your android manifest, you will need to add code to clearly request them to the user.

Here is a package that can help you request permissions to users : https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler